# Metrics such as CPU, Memory, disk in windows

Tags: fluent-bit

I am using fluent-bit to collect metrics such as CPU, Disk, Memory in windows  but unable to collect? Does anyone know how to collect data of these metrics using fluent-bit?

Answer (score 0):

Ap per the [doc](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/inputs/node-exporter-metrics), node-exporter plugin which collects CPU / Disk / Network metrics is **only supported on Linux** based operating systems.